# Inserting different fields into a table by comparing two other fields from different table

Tags: php, jquery, sql

[Form built with HTML AND CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KP3M.png)

```
CREATE TABLE surgery (
    surgery_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    doc_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES doctor(doc_id),
    nurse_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES nurse(nurse_id),
    surgery_status VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL CHECK (surgery_status IN (`Success`, `Fialled`)),
    description NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL
)  ENGINE=INNODB CHARSET=UTF8 COLLATE UTF8_BIN;
```

The surgery table has patient id and doctor id which is linked to patient table and doctor table respectively. I want to collect the names of the patient and doctor with the form but insert their id rather than their names into the surgery table.

Comment: I'm unsure, are you asking how to collect variables from HTML to insert into Mysql? Or are you asking how to save the patient name and doctor name based on their ID, to save their ID instead of their names?

Comment: On your form, are you selecting patient and doctor, or inserting their names?

Comment: Collecting patient name and doctor name based on their ID , to insert their ID instead of their names

Comment: No, you do not want to put the names in the `surgery` table.  You just want to write a query using `JOIN`s that looks up the names when you need them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use subquery concept for this kind of scenario.
Example:

```
SELECT *,(SELECT patient_name FROM patient WHERE patient.id = surgery.patient_id) AS _patient_name,
(SELECT doctor_name FROM doctor WHERE doctor.id = surgery.doctor_id) AS _doctor_name FROM surgery
```